# UITextView bounces uncontrollably while typing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, uitextview

I have been having this problem with a few of my UITextViews on my most recent project. All I have done is added a UITextView onto a ViewController and added some constraints to it. When I run my program and attempted to type in the UITextView it begins to bounce out of control. For instance, when I type the first character, the view will slide down and out of the screen. Then when I type the next few characters the textview will bounce back up to where I can see what I typed. Then I type a few more, and once again it bounces out of the screen. Has anyone else experienced this?

Also, sometimes the text will start in the middle of the UITextView.

Comment: put some relevant code here. add a gif link if you can.

Comment: Please add some relevant code along with the description of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this code to `textViewDidChange:` method

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text?.characters.count ?? 0 > 0 {
        let range = NSMakeRange(textView.text!.characters.count - 1, 1)
        textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range);
    }
}
```

It helped me.